# SAP UI5: Navigation from Master page and Detail page through two different OData URLs

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am trying to create a Master - Detail page using OData servicea in SAPUI5. Everything works fine in the Master page. Meaning I'm able to populate the list with valid data from SAP backend using an OData URL.

Now what I want to achieve is, to call a second OData URL to fetch the detail values and populate that in the page.

My **Master.controller.js**

```
handleListSelect : function (evt) { 
        var context = evt.getParameter("listItem").getBindingContext(); 
        this.nav.to("Detail", context); 
         console.log('evt.getSource: ' + evt.getSource());
            console.log('evt.getBindingContext: ' + evt.getSource().getBindingContext());
    }
```

Console Output gives

```
"evt.getSource: Element sap.m.List#Master--list" sap-ui-core.js line 80 > eval:31
"evt.getBindingContext: undefined"
```

I'm unable to populate values in the detail page from the second URL. Can anyone guide or help me on this?

My **Compenent.js**

```
createContent : function() {

    // create root view
    var oView = sap.ui.view({
        id : "app",
        viewName : "sap.ui.demo.myFiori.view.App",
        type : "JS",
        viewData : {
            component : this
        }
    });

     // Using OData model to connect against a real service
     var url = "/MyFioriUI5/proxy/sap/opu/odata/sap/XXXXXX;mo/";
     var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(url, true, "", "");
     oView.setModel(oModel);

    // set i18n model
    var i18nModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
        bundleUrl : "i18n/messageBundle.properties"
    });
    oView.setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");

    // set device model
    var deviceModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
            isPhone : jQuery.device.is.phone,
            isNoPhone : !jQuery.device.is.phone,
            listMode : (jQuery.device.is.phone) ? "None" : "SingleSelectMaster",
            listItemType : (jQuery.device.is.phone) ? "Active" : "Inactive"
    });
    deviceModel.setDefaultBindingMode("OneWay");
    oView.setModel(deviceModel, "device");

        // Using a local model for offline development
//      var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("model/mock.json");
//      oView.setModel(oModel);

    // done
    return oView;
}
```

My **Detail.controller.js**

```
sap.ui.controller("sap.ui.demo.myFiori.view.Detail", {

    handleNavButtonPress : function(evt) {
        this.nav.back("Master");
    },

    onBeforeRendering : function() {
//      this.byId("SupplierForm").bindElement("BusinessPartner");
    },

    handleApprove : function(evt) {
        // show confirmation dialog
        var bundle = this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle();
        sap.m.MessageBox.confirm(bundle.getText("ApproveDialogMsg"), function(oAction) {
            if (sap.m.MessageBox.Action.OK === oAction) {
                // notify user
                var successMsg = bundle.getText("ApproveDialogSuccessMsg");
                sap.m.MessageToast.show(successMsg);
                // TODO call proper service method and update model (not part of this session)
            }
        },

        bundle.getText("ApproveDialogTitle"));
    }
});
```

Comment: What event from your List does `handleListSelect` actually handle?

Comment: When you tap/click on any item in the List, 'handleListSelect' is called.

Comment: Its been a while since you posted the question.. but just in case you haven't found the solution yet, can you post the code for your 'Detail.controller.js' as well ?

Comment: Thanks @Breakpoint for your reply. Really appreciate your concern. Yes, I've still not found a solution yet. I've updated my question with the 'Detail.controller.js' code.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the second URL you are refering to, but we handle it this way.

In Component.js:

```
var oView = sap.ui.view({
    id: "app",
    viewName: "fom.test.app.view.App",
    type: "JS",
    viewData: { component : this }
});
var dataModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("/fom/fiori/odata/FOM/mobile_app_srv", true);
oView.setModel(dataModel);
```

This connects the master view to the data for all the list items.

In the App.controller.js we make use of the onNavigation function, defined in Detail.controller.js. That means when routing to the detail view, the onNavigation function is called before the view is set up.

App.controller.js:

```
to : function (pageId, context) {

    var app = this.getView().app;

    // load page on demand
    var master = ("Master" === pageId);
    if (app.getPage(pageId, master) === null) {
        var page = sap.ui.view({
            id : pageId,
            viewName : "fom.test.app.view.view." + pageId,
            type : "XML"
        });
        page.getController().nav = this;
        app.addPage(page, master);
        jQuery.sap.log.info("app controller > loaded page: " + pageId);
    }

    // show the page
    app.to(pageId);

    // set data context on the page
    if (context) {
        var page = app.getPage(pageId);
        page.setBindingContext(context);

        try{
            var oController = page.getController();
            oController.onNavigation(context);
        }
        catch(e){ }
    }
},
```

Detail.controller.js:

```
onNavigation: function(context) {
    this.getView().bindElement({
        path: context.sPath,
        parameters: {
            select: "Id," +
                    "Lifnam," +
                    "Rmwwr," +
                    "Waers," +
                    "Sendedatum," +
                    "Workflowtyp," +
                    "Sktodat," +
                    "Stufe," +
                    "MonFrgstA," +
                    "Bukrs," +
                    "Belnr," +
                    "Gjahr," +
                    "EdcObject," +
                    "BstatTxt",
            expand: "Positions"
        }
    });
},
```

The bindElements() function, connects the detail view to the results of another web service call, which fetches all attributes mentioned in select and the line items which are fetched with the expand.

Now your first webservice call is loading only the data relevant for the master view list, and the second one all the information of the selected list item.

When you use the newer routing functionality of UI5, you will need to find another place for the hook. I haven't built that in yet.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> oView.setModel(oModel);
> ```

You have this statement twice - the one would override the other - you need to provide an alternate reference to the second instance:

e.g.

```
oView.setModel(oModel, "local")
```